# How to create a for loop with dictionary and function with multiple variables

Tags: python

I am struggling to create a `for` loop that works for this problem I'm trying to solve involving a `dictionary` consisting of *employee ids* and a list of their interests. This is the dict, called "`idkey`":

```
{'0': ['Hadoop', 'Big Data', 'HBas', 'Java', 'Spark', 'Storm', 'Cassandra'],
 '1': ['NoSQL', 'MongoDB', 'Cassandra', 'HBase', 'Postgres'],
 '2': ['Python', 'skikit-learn', 'scipy', 'numpy', 'statsmodels', 'pandas'],
 '3': ['R', 'Python', 'statistics', 'regression', 'probability'],
 '4': ['machine learning', 'regression', 'decision trees', 'libsvm'],
 '5': ['Python', 'R', 'Java', 'C++', 'Haskell', 'programming languages'],
 '6': ['statistics', 'probability', 'mathematics', 'theory'],
 '7': ['machine learning', 'scikit-learn', 'Mahout', 'neural networks'],
 '8': ['neural networks','deep learning','Big Data','artificial intelligence'],
 '9': ['Hadoop', 'Java', 'MapReduce', 'Big Data']}
```

And I need to match each employee based on their interests. This is the function I've written:

```
def InterestingFriends(employee1, employee2):
sharedinterests = list(set(idkey[employee1]).intersection(idkey[employee2]))
if len(sharedinterests) > 0:
    print("Employee", employee1, "and", employee2, "are a match based on their shared interest of", sharedinterests)
else:
    None
```

This is as far as I got with the for loop

```
for e1 in list(idkey.keys()):
    InterestingFriends(e1, '0')
```

Which outputs:

```
Employee 0 and 0 are a match based on their shared interest of ['Spark', 'Storm', 'Big Data', 'Java', 'Cassandra', 'HBas', 'Hadoop']
Employee 1 and 0 are a match based on their shared interest of ['Cassandra']
Employee 5 and 0 are a match based on their shared interest of ['Java']
Employee 8 and 0 are a match based on their shared interest of ['Big Data']
Employee 9 and 0 are a match based on their shared interest of ['Java', 'Big Data', 'Hadoop']
```

Obviously, I hard-coded this in. I just can't seem to figure out how to get the other variable in there to iterate with each of the other employees. Any ideas? I have tried a `for` loop similar to above with `e1`, `e2` instead of *just e1*, but I always get an error.

Answer (score 3):

You want itertools.combinations, you can get the combinations of all keys using

```
import itertools

for e1, e2 in itertools.combinations( idkey.keys(), 2 ):
    InterestingFriends(e1,e2)
```

I think this is much prettier than the nested for-loops.